# How to Post JSON Array/string value?

Tags: json, rest, postman

I need to post some values to a REST service. I'm using POSTMAN rest client for my test and i can post string, integer, boolean values to rest service there is no problem. But i could not post array values ;

I am using this parameter, this parameter is working except Array values ;

```
{
"parameters": [
    {
      "type": "string",
      "name": "nameandsurname",
      "value": {"string":{ "value": "myname"}}
    },
    {
      "type": "Array/string",
      "name": "arrayvariable",
      **"value": {"string":{ "value": "value1"}}** This line is not working...
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Do you expect an attribute called `string` in your JSON model in the backend? I mean this JSON is valid but what is your expected JSON format?

Comment: backend attribute is array of string. ı want  to post array item value to my array attribute.

Comment: What's this array name?

Comment: in this sample the name is "arrayvariable"

Comment: So you need to name it accordingly in your JSON, change it from `"value": {"string":{ "value": "myname"}}` to `"value": {"arrayvariable":[ "value": "myname"}]` also use `[]` for array instead of `{}`.

Comment: I changed with this "value": {"arrayvariable":[ "value": "arrayvalue1"}] but i am getting error 400

Comment: Sorry my bad change it to `"arrayvariable": [ "value", "myname"]` , this is a valid array.

Comment: sorry chdsk it's not working,But i found solution. Thanks you very much for your helps. parameter should be ; "value":{    "array":{    "elements":[    {    "string":{    "value":"value1"  }  },  {    "string":{    "value":"value2"  }  },  {    "string":{    "value":"value3"  }  }  ]  }  }

Answer (score 1):

In Postman you can post JSON this way:

1. Select method POST
2. In section Body choose *raw* and content-type JSON(application/json)
3. Paster your JSON into Body

You can download this export from Postman and try it
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulmoc8n8gmgb076/tests.postman_collection.json?dl=0

Comment: hi zelenyjan, you had been sent to me the same parameters, "value": {"string":{ "value": "value1"}} is not working

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks